# Що означає словосполучення "рузю бузю"?

Tags: вживання-слів, значення-слів, словосполучення

Натрапила на одну весільну пісню, яка називається ["Дай рузю бузю"](http://4musics.me/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B9_%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B9). Зацікавило словосполучення **"рузю бузю"**. Спершу подумала, що, можливо, це *звернення до дівчини,з проханням про те, аби вона дала бузю* (теж невідомо, що це), однак тут не виділено комами і написано з малої літери, тому варіант, що це ім’я виключаю. Звертаюся, як завжди, у СУМ-11, проте ні [першого](http://sum.in.ua/s/buzja), ні [другого](http://sum.in.ua/s/ruzja) слова там не знаходжу.

То що ж у цій пісні означає словосполучення "рузю бузю"?

Comment: Зверніся до словника польської мови: звідти ноги ростуть))

Comment: @Олег, дякуємо за наведення. Але Ви могли б, будь ласка, трішки конкретизувати? Бо зараз це більш схоже на коментар/підказку, ніж на повну відповідь.

Comment: @Sasha, це, власне, і є коментар. "Buzię" в поляків - обличчя. Але я думаю, що наша "бузя", походить від іншого полського слова: не знаю, як пишуть, але вимовляють "пуся", тобто "милашка", "крихітка", чи щось в тому роді.
Але то неточно. Тому - словник)

Comment: @DimaDima, по-моєму, те, що Ви хотіли вписати в текст запитання, заслуговує бути окремою відповіддю.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Виконавець Андрій Кок співає заклик до дівчат: "Дай, Рузю, Бузю дай". Це кличний відмінок імен.

[Рузя — Розалія Рузалія Розалька, Розонька, Розочка, Рузалька, Руза, Рузя, Рузина, Рузька](http://kurufin.ru/html/Ukrainian/ukrainian_r.html)

[Бузя — пестливе ім'я, створене з Естер-Люби: Люба-Любузя-Бузя...](http://www.ukrcenter.com/%D0%9B%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0/%D0%A8%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC/47897-1/%D0%9F%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C)